# Javascript, CSS, HTML5 IDE that starts with a W

Tags: javascript, ruby, html, css

I found a great new IDE a few weeks ago and installed it on my Windows laptop.  I then decided it would be nicer to set it up on my Linux laptop.  I uninstalled it from Windows and just recently had the chance to try and download it on my Linux.  Now I can't find it anywhere.  It's based on javascript and I believe Ruby as well.  It starts with a W and is a goofy name.  Wandaba or Wandava or something like that.  It has a really smooth and simple design.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure you're referring to [Wakanda](http://www.wakanda.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), found on the first page of [this Google search](http://www.google.com/#q=html+ide+for+windows).